# Conditional cumulative sum in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I have a table of that has scores for games. Each player has a number of games that come within one or more sessions and are arranged in order within these sessions.

```
create table games (
  player int, 
  session int,
  ord int,
  score int
 );

 insert into games (player, session, ord, score)
 VALUES
   ('1', '1', '1', '3'),
   ('1', '1', '1', '-5'),
   ('1', '1', '2', '1'),
   ('1', '1', '3', '3'),
   ('2', '1', '1', '1'),
   ('2', '1', '2', '2'),
   ('2', '2', '1', '-2'),
   ('2', '2', '2', '3'),
   ('2', '2', '3', '2');



+--------+---------+-----+---------+
| player | session | ord |  score  |
+--------+---------+-----+---------+
|      1 |       1 |   1 |       3 |
|      1 |       1 |   2 |      -5 |
|      1 |       1 |   3 |       1 |
|      1 |       1 |   4 |       3 |
|      2 |       1 |   1 |       1 |
|      2 |       1 |   2 |       2 |
|      2 |       2 |   1 |      -2 |
|      2 |       2 |   2 |       3 |
|      2 |       2 |   3 |       2 |
+--------+---------+-----+---------+
```

I would like the **negative scores to cascade down within each session** so that they are deducted from future scores until they are fully accounted. Scores in different sessions should not affect each other and **positive scores should not cascade down**.

To put it concisely, I would need conditional cumulative sum that only affects negative numbers.

```
+--------+---------+-----+-------+--------+
| player | session | ord | score | target |
+--------+---------+-----+-------+--------+
|      1 |       1 |   1 |     3 |      3 |
|      1 |       1 |   2 |    -5 |     -5 | No cumulation because previous score is positive
|      1 |       1 |   3 |     1 |     -4 | 1-5=-4
|      1 |       1 |   4 |     3 |     -1 | 3-4=-1 Cumulation because previous score is negative after cascading negative scores
|      2 |       1 |   1 |     1 |      1 |
|      2 |       1 |   2 |     2 |      2 | No cumulation because previous score is positive
|      2 |       2 |   1 |    -2 |     -2 | 
|      2 |       2 |   2 |     3 |      1 | 3-2=1
|      2 |       2 |   3 |     2 |      2 | No cumulation because previous score is positive
+--------+---------+-----+-------+--------+
```

Comment: why first row win_loss -5 ?.. In fact please explain all numbers - i see no arithmetic here - no formula

Comment: I simplified the question a bit and changed to talking about scores instead of winnings and losses. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: please the formula, how you get the value of the score and the target? why is it -5; -5 in first row?, why 1;-4 in second etc